# In emacs, how to execute external command not as a emacs process?

Tags: windows, emacs, windows-7, elisp

For some external program (not all), I want the program running independently outside Emacs, after executing the command. In another word, if I close Emacs, the external program can still run.

PS: my operating system is windows.

Comment: Run your command with nohup, man nohup for more information. But be more precise which OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, my OS is window7. I am afraid nohup does not work in Windows, at least it is not convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `(w32-shell-execute "start" "myprog" "args")` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Now I find `(w32-shell-execute "open" "myprog" "arguments")` works. But `(w32-shell-execute "start myprog")` seems not work.

Comment: try "start" instead of "open"