# How to delete a process from Emacs without killing the subprocess

Tags: emacs, elisp

When using `start-process` with Emacs on Windows XP, deleting the process or killing Emacs also kills the subprocess -- e.g., viewing a PDF with another application.

How would one go about removing a process from the list of active processes within Emacs, without sending a kill signal to the subprocess -- i.e., leave the subprocess running, but tell Emacs to forget about it?

Here is a related thread that discusses using `w32-shell-execute` as an alternative to `start-process`:  [In emacs, how to execute external command not as a emacs process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335853/in-emacs-how-to-execute-external-command-not-as-a-emacs-process)  I have verified that `w32-shell-execute` is a viable alternative for Windows XP.

I am very fond of `start-process` and would still be interested in knowing (please) whether it is possible to delete a process from Emacs without killing the corresponding subprocess.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: On Windows XP, I was attempting to use `start-process` and `set-process-sentinel` to run latexmk, then launch SumatraPDF with forward sync, and then cleanup the LaTeX auxiliary files.  On OSX, this is not a problem because the process of launching Skim finishes successfully and the application remains visible when Emacs quits.  On Windows XP, however, SumatraPDF maintains an open Emacs process indefinitely -- this causes two problems:  (1) closing Emacs kills SumatraPDF, and (2) cleanup of the auxiliary files cannot be made dependent upon a successful display of the pdf file with forward sync.

Comment: I was trying to think of a way resolve both of those two issues.  Using `w32-shell-execute` resolves the problem of being able to close Emacs, but I still do not have the ability to make cleanup dependent upon successfully launching the pdf viewer.  `(sit-for 2)` is a workaround, but is not as sophisticated as `set-process-sentinel`.